# Talend how to copy one db to another

Tags: database, oracle, talend

I need to copy a lot af tables from one db to another. And i want to do it in a fast way. So, what it the fastest way to do that? I'm new to talend,  i know that is possible to do something like that: toracleinput->map->toracleoutput. But it will take a lot of time to do it for 40 tables.

Comment: What is your tMap doing there?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to transfer all the tables then you can use [tTransferDatabase](https://www.talendforge.org/exchange/?eid=457&product=tos&action=view&nav=1,1,1)
refer document pages for more details.

You can download tTransferDatabase component from above link and then install it with TOS.

once that is done this component will be displayed on palate. drag and drop it on job designer. configure like below.

1. it will ask for source connection and target connection.
2. Create tOracleConnection for Target & source and provide it to tTransferDatabase component.
3. Select Migration type " schema & data".
4. See image for more details. 
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: This is not a good answer by itself. Try to add more information from the linked page or even a tutorial on how to use the tTransferDatabase component.

Comment: apologize, but we don`t have much information about this component, I will write blog on dwetl.com for this component.

Comment: If you have enterprise, then you can try to use dynamic schema, and do tOracleInput (select * ) -> tOracleOutput

Comment: @UmeshR Sorry, I must have overlooked your comment. Deleted by comment

Comment: This only works for Oracle? Postgres datasoureces does not show up.