# ttransferdatabase in Talend is not working as expected

Tags: talend

I need to transfer all tables from a db A to a db B. I found [Talend how to copy one db to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28743559/talend-how-to-copy-one-db-to-another/28743675); checked all the documentation but for whatever reason, the transfer of tables is not happening. Is any additional step required apart from Source connection, Target connection and TransferDatabase?
[image]

The error:

```
    at com.devjpcb.transferdatabase.TransferDatabase.getPlatformSource(TransferDatabase.java:153)
    at com.devjpcb.transferdatabase.TransferDatabase.copySchemaToDatabase(TransferDatabase.java:247)
    at central_db.drop_0_1.drop.tTransferDatabase_1Process(drop.java:744)
    at central_db.drop_0_1.drop.tDBConnection_2Process(drop.java:974)
    at central_db.drop_0_1.drop.runJobInTOS(drop.java:1317)
    at central_db.drop_0_1.drop.main(drop.java:1053)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ddlutils.PlatformFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Do you have any error messages ? Are the rights correctly configured for your users ? (creation, insert, etc). we are lacking elements to give an answer.

Comment: @Corentin, updated the question.

Comment: sorry I don't know this component. Perhaps link components in this order : tDBConnection1-->tDBConnection_-->tTransferDatabase. As it is built in your screenshot, talend won't know which one is the starter component.